# How to position a node relative to two other nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I am very new to Tikz and am trying to draw a diagram with 5 nodes. My code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{node distance = 3 cm, every state/.style = {semithick}, every edge/.style = {draw, ->, > = stealth', semithick}}

\node[state] (2) {2};
\node[state, right = of 2] (3) {3};
\node[state, below right = of 2] (1) {1};
\node[state, below left = of 1] (4) {4};
\node[state, below right = of 1] (5) {5};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that I would like node 1 to be exactly below and in the middle nodes 2 and 3, so I am trying to code something like `\node[state, below right = of 2 and below left = of 3] (1) {1}`. However, this does not work.

How can I amend my code to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you change the drawing order? First node 1 and then nodes 2 and 3 from it.

Comment: @Ignasi Brilliant!! I never even thought of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `calc` library define a point between `3` and `2` called `a`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{node distance = 3 cm, every state/.style = {semithick}, every edge/.style = {draw, ->, > = stealth', semithick}}

\node[state] (2) {2};
\node[state, right = of 2] (3) {3};
\coordinate(a) at ($(2)!0.5!(3)$);
\node[state, below= of a] (1) {1};
\node[state, below left = of 1] (4) {4};
\node[state, below right = of 1] (5) {5};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```